# How to toggle panel header on sidebar vertically in bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Panel with header on sidebar is working fine but I am unable to 
toggle the header by adding another tab to it, here html,css and links to add in head tag are given.I want same panel with toggle header functionality how to acheive it.how to make it responsive. when I tried to add another title to it first title is not displaying.

```css
 .panel
    {
    position: relative;
    height:100px;
    }

    .panel-default > .panel-leftheading
    {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-color: #ddd;
    }

    .panel-primary > .panel-leftheading
    {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #428bca;
    border-color: #428bca;
    }
    .panel-leftheading
    {
    width: 42px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    }

     .panel-lefttitle
    {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: inherit;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: left top;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: left top;
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform-origin: left top;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .panel-rightbody
    {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 45px;
    padding: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- ************* --->
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
   </script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    
    <div class="container">
         
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-leftheading">
              <h3 class="panel-lefttitle">Panel title</h3>
              </div>
             <div class="panel-rightbody">
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod .</p>
              </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is your requirement actually?

Comment: I want to toggle the panel title which is on left side by adding another title

Comment: do you mean on click hide first panel and display second panel?

Comment: yes the title should display on side vertically as i mentioned in the code

Comment: I fixed style and agre <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> @user7628723

Comment: Sorry I am not getting @NicolásAlarcónR.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this, working fine for me.

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" style="min-height:300px;"> 
  <div  class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="home-vr">Home Tab.</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="profile-vr">Profile Tab.</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="messages-vr">Messages Tab.</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="settings-vr">Settings Tab.</div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
</div>

<style>
.tabs-left,{
 border-bottom: none;
 padding-top: 2px;
}
.tabs-left {
 border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-left>li, .tabs-right>li {
 float: none;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.tabs-left>li {
 margin-right: -1px;
}

.tabs-left>li.active>a,
.tabs-left>li.active>a:hover,
.tabs-left>li.active>a:focus {
border-bottom-color: #ddd;
border-right-color: transparent;
}

.tabs-left>li>a {
 border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
 margin-right: 0;
 display:block;
 }

 .vertical-text {
 margin-top:50px;
 border: none;
 position: relative;
 }
 .vertical-text>li {
  height: 20px;
 width: 120px;
 margin-bottom: 100px;
 }
 .vertical-text>li>a {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
 border-right-color: transparent;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
}
 .vertical-text>li.active>a,
  .vertical-text>li.active>a:hover,
 .vertical-text>li.active>a:focus {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #ddd;
  border-left-color: #ddd;
  }
 .vertical-text.tabs-left {
 left: -50px;
}
 .vertical-text.tabs-right {
  right: -50px;
 }

 .vertical-text.tabs-left>li {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
 </style>
```